# TFS - Getting all the change sets included in the last get

Tags: tfs

I am creating a batch build script.
I need a tfs cmd command to print all the change sets included in my get.

i failed to google it so far, appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you try `tf get` command?

Comment: your joking right? if you dont know the answer, dont answer at all. tf get doesnt show you the change sets changed, just the files changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution.
You can use the tf history command, you can compare the history of the local workbench vs the server.

Answer (score 1):

Try this command:

```
tf history xxx.sln /noprompt /v:Cxx~W
```

**Cxx:** Get the changset of the time you would do the last get.

**W:** Specifies the version in your workspace.(Current)

[image]

Comment: Cxx means i need to tell him the change set, not helping my problem, the other way i found as stated in my answer is to do: tf history.. /version:W /stopafter:1 /noprompt, and /stopafter:20 /noprompt. this way i know my local latest change set and i can compare to the server's last 20 for ex